# Excel Split() converting number to Date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement a SPLIT() function to parse a string in EXCEL and distribute the result to adjacent cells on the same form.  The following is working as expected, except when a parsed term is a Number.

"0.25" parses to "1/0/1900  6:00:00 AM"

I tried cstr() on the resulting strAttr value, but seems to have no effect.  Any ideas?

```
 Sub splitText()

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim strText As String
 Dim strAttr As Variant
 Dim strFirst As String
 Dim NumRows As Integer

    strFirst = "A4"

    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Range(strFirst).Select
    NumRows = Range(strFirst, Range(strFirst).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    For x = 1 To NumRows

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        strText = ActiveCell.Value
        strAttr = Split(strText, " ")

        For i = 0 To UBound(strAttr)
            Cells(x + 4, i + 2).Value = strAttr(i)
        Next i

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the cell on the Worksheet pre-formatted to Date? You could format everything to General before dropping the values in.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

I forced a (') to the front of the string, which seems to provide the desired result, except everything will be = TEXT:

```
    For i = 0 To UBound(strAttr)
        Cells(x + 4, i + 2).Value = "'" & strAttr(i)
    Next i
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this and retain "0.25" as a Number value?

Thanks,

mark

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  Replace:

```
strText = ActiveCell.Value
```

with:

```
strText = ActiveCell.Text
```